# Docker-compose corrupted directory when shared a multiple file/directory in the same mounting point

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume, mount-point

I have a service in Docker-compose where I mount a directory and file in the same directory mount point.
my docker-compose.yml:

```
 version: '2'
services:
  web:
    volumes:
      - /c/www/:/var/folder1
      - /c/src/resources/xslt.xsl:/var/folder1/file1
      - /c/src/resources/apiJS:/var/folder1/file2
      - /c/src/resources/api_js.min.js:/var/folder1/file3
```

the problem is after starting service web I find file1,file2,file3 in host directory /www. How I can mount file1,file2,file3 without appearing in the host directory /c/www/

I am using boo2docker with docker engine 1.13 and docker-compose 1.11.2